# Highstock addSeries to specified Y axis

Tags: highcharts

There, bizarrely, doesn't seem to be a way to target which Y axis a series is added to using the chart.addSeries() method. Nothing here (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.addSeries%28%29) about targeting axes. This results in lines destined to be plotted against the oposite axis being incorrectly plotted in the left hand one; something I would have thought to be a basic prerequisite of the method.

Has anyone seen any hacks or plugins that might solve this or know where to go in the source to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the [`yAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.yAxis) property is used to specify in the series configuration object you pass into `addSeries` as the `options` parameter.

Comment: Correct... weirdly the documentation tells us that the options property should be an object made of the parameters under [plotOptions.series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series), not [series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series)

Comment: @FusePumpDev It's not just you, the way the `series` config options are documented is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add serie as you define series in Highcharts, so you can use yAxis index. Take look at example http://jsfiddle.net/68Fp4/1/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: ADBE,
        yAxis:1
    });
});
```